# DNS records could not be found. Certificate activation will retry automatically

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, certificate, google-app-engine, gcloud

Our website is down and it is showing certificate is expired. When I check the custom domain settings section in GCP, I am getting the following warning.

We have removed the records and re-added them, but showing the same warning.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjJ3B.png)

Comment: If you create or modify DNS resource records, you must wait. Sometimes up to 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

if we discuss "hire.codeclouds.com" it seems there are redirect to https://www.codeclouds.com/top-developers-for-hire/ and certificate is OK.. Any ideas?

and, DNS-checker reports it is OK with initals website https://dnschecker.org/#A/hire.codeclouds.com